# Using bit fields in struct and reading an instance from Memory with C++

Tags: c++, struct, endianness, bit-fields

```
unsigned __int16 var16bit= 6545; //00011001 10010001
unsigned __int8 var8bit;
memcpy(&var8bit, &var16bit, sizeof(var8bit));
cout << var8bit; // result is 145 which is 10010001
```

When working with little endian machine, lsb is written to memory first then offset is added to address if necessary. In this example a 16bit integer is copied to 8bit integer and it losts its msb side because of target space is not enough. Reverse behaviour happens in big endian machines.

There is another example below

here is my structure

```
struct Account 
{
   unsigned int dollar : 4;
   unsigned int euro : 4;
   unsigned int pound : 4;
   unsigned int ruble : 4;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Account myWealthyAccount = {};
    myWealthyAccount.dollar = 2; // 0010
    myWealthyAccount.euro = 3; // 0011
    myWealthyAccount.pound = 4; // 0100
    myWealthyAccount.ruble = 5; // 0101

    unsigned __int16 sum;
    memcpy(&sum, &myWealthyAccount, sizeof(myWealthyAccount));
    cout << sum;
    // result is 0101010000110010  ruble pound euro dollar
    unsigned __int8 sum8Bit;
    memcpy(&sum8Bit, &myWealthyAccount, sizeof(sum8Bit));
    cout << sum8Bit; // result is 50 which is 0011 0010 euro dollar

    return 0;
}
```

> 0101010000110010  ruble pound euro dollar

Why was it ordered as ruble pound euro dollar why not the opposite way?

Why is ruble is beside msb and dollar is beside lsb?

Is this about being little endian or big endian machine? Or Is this about Struct? Is this about compiler?

If I run this example in big endian machine, what result would occur? Why?

I'm open to every advises like articles, videos, websites about the topic.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need to use bitfields at all? It's almost always a mistake.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Can you assume that I'm using it? Also little explanation about "why this is such a mistake" would be great.

Comment: Well, I'd advise _not_ using it, because the code will be slow and (depending on circumstances) may take up more memory than not using it, and it won't be portable. You have to have a very positive reason for using bitfields, and there are not many such reasons.

Comment: Order of packing bitfields in struct is implementation defined, and could be related to endiannes or compiler writer mood. Do not ever rely on bitfields ordering.

Comment: However, I would not immediately say that nobody should be using bitfields - sometimes using bitfields is justified (for example, by making data smaller, they improve locality). What you loose in shifts, you save in a trip down memory lane.

Comment: @SergeyA thank you Sergey. "Do not ever rely on bitfields ordering" you mean I must control it before releasing it? It may vary depending on endiannes or compiler writer mood. Compiler writer mood seemed more reasonable for me. Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

"Why was it ordered as ruble pound euro dollar why not the opposite way?"

I copied your code and got the exact same result. 
On your first example the 16 bit integer is stored like that 00011001 10010001. So if you take only the lsb you get 10010001. But your Bitfield is stored like 0101 0100 0011 0010.

If you look on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field under notes:
*"Also, on some platforms, bit fields are packed left-to-right, on others right-to-left"*. So it is implementation defined which order you have.